# Possible to read sensor values of phone just by bluetooth?

Tags: android, iphone, bluetooth, sensors, android-sensors

When you connect bluetooth speakers or an external device you are connecting them using the Android/iPhones bluetooth settings. The android OS is doing this. Example:[iPhone Bluetooth Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gfqi.jpg)

These bluetooth speakers do not need an additional app that is required to download to work with the speakers. The phone seems to recognize the bluetooth device's profile as a headset/speaker and automatically gives any audio output to the speaker.

Is it possible to replace the bluetooth speakers with a device that could read sensor values (GPS,Gyro,etc). For example, could you pair a device through the phone's bluetooth settings menu and then have sensor values of the phone given to that device.

From my reading the device would have to have a "Health Device Profile" in order to read sensor information, but I have no idea what kind of chip to use, or if this is even possible.

Any insight, suggestions, or knowledge would help a million. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible, my experience with anadafruit board, and an accidently ordered BLE addon. BLE(Bluetooth Low Energy) is nice for low power uses, but with optimized Bluetooth use it doesnt take much battery either.

So yes it is possible.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know what kind of profile I would have to register my ble device as to have the gyroscopic/accelerometer data sent over from the phone? Essentially, I am not sure how to ask a phone to send me its sensor data over bluetooth

Comment: It would have to be a specific GATT profile, off the top of my head I'm unsure.

Comment: Right, I have not been able to find one. Most of them call for the peripheral device to give information to the phone, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can certainly scan and pair a BLE device through Android's Bluetooth settings, but the only GATT profile that can be used as far as I know without any app, i.e. built into the system is the HID profile.

On iOS the same applies there almost, except that you can only scan devices which advertise specific GATT service in the Bluetooth settings UI. But iOS supports at least HID, Battery status profile and midi (I think).